# MYSQL how to increment column count if different combination row exist

Tags: mysql, sql

MYSQL how to increment column count if different combination row exist
for example if table have

```
count   user   certNo
0       a      001
0       b      886
```

if same user with different certNo comes then i need to increment count by 1,
like

```
count   user     certNo
  0       a      001
  0       b      886
  1       a      673
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row number()`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by user order by certNo) - 1 as count,
      user, certNo
from t;
```

Comment: @manoj . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 1):

For legacy MySQL version you can use next query:

```
select 
    t.*,
    count(t1.certNo) as count
from test t
left join test t1 on t1.user = t.user and t1.certNo < t.certNo
group by t.user, t.certNo;
```

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1aee5299fe4eddb0d845505f2d7e467b&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)